# Play Stream from ShoutCast Server on Windows Phone RunTime 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, streaming, shoutcast

Please, Is there someone there that can help me? I am trying to play a stream from a ShoutCast server on Windows Phone RunTime 8.1 and I had no success so far.

My company has 3 stream servers; 1 IceCast and 2 ShoutCast.

This is my code for IceCast server:

```
Uri audioSourceUrl = new Uri(url,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetUriSource(audioSourceUrl);
               BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Play();
```

I set the url to the background appication the app has and it is done. 
But with shoutcast I cannot do that.

I've tried to change the url with no success to :

> 1- "http://IP:PORT/;stream.mp3";
>
> 2-http://IP:PORT/;&type=mp3
>
> 3-http://IP:PORT/;

I read I have to manipulate the stream to get it working but I have no idea.

Can someone show me a light?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello Windows phone 8.1 media control not by default support shoutcast stream to play

Comment: I know, but is there another way to do it? The application is almost done. I just need it to finish. Is there a way to convert WPhone Runtime to Silverlight?

Comment: create a silverlight project and import it to your project

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda, did you create a wpruntime or silverlight project to your radio? What do you mean by adding a silverlight project to my runtime project? Will it still be a runtime project after that or no?

Comment: It will remain as runtime project only

Comment: I did not get any clue. I could not do it.

Comment: The problem you're likely running into is the non-standard status line in the HTTP-like response of the SHOUTcast server.  It returns `ICY 200 OK` instead of `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.  Must you use SHOUTcast on the server?  If you control the streaming servers, let me know... I run an alternative called AudioPump that is HTTP-compliant and should work for you out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoutcast format isn’t supported on the platform.
You can support the protocol yourself by developing a custom media stream source (in Silverlight) or custom media source (Windows RT). However both tasks are hard.

There’re several third-party Silverlight libraries implementing media stream source.

- [Shoutcast MSS](https://shoutcastmss.codeplex.com/) — freeware and opensource, abandoned, can be fixed, but will take a lot of time. I tried that but failed, developed my own one that works OK (see below)
- [Apollo SDK](http://www.apollosdk.com/) — commercial, €200 per app, support both Silverlight (8.0+) and WinRT 8.1.
- [Jupiter SDK](http://www.jupitersdk.com/) — commercial, €100 per app, only support WinRT 8.1, you probably need this one.
- [My own one](https://github.com/Const-me/SkyFM) — freeware and opensource, only supports Silverlight, works on WP 7.5+.
- New Microsoft's [FFmpegInterop](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop) - only support WinRT 8.1+, free.

Comment: Thank you Soonts.  I´ve given up with runtime. Now I am developing on e for Silverlight 8.0. I hope it works with Silverlight 8.1

Comment: You're welcome, but shoutcast isn't supported by Silverlight either.
You still need to develop or license a custom media stream source.

Comment: I found an example that uses shoutcast. I am gonna try to study it.

Comment: @debeka Some time ago I've open sourced my implementation: https://github.com/Const-me/SkyFM